# How to show an image from the filesystem in a Notes form?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to show an image from the filesystem in a Notes client form.
I tried using the Picture object, but even the computed image will only allow pictures from the resources. Changing the resources seems to be impossible without expensive third party libraries. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use «Pass-Thru HTML» feature. You can use `<img>` tag with your image as `src` attribute. So, just type `<img src="`, add `Computed Text` here and type `" />`. Select all typed text and make it «Pass-Thru HTML» («Text\Pass-Thru HTML» menu). You will see something like this:

[image: Pass-Thru HTML]

In `Computed Text` formula type the name of field which holds your image path and save the form:

[image: ComputedText]

Now, you can use this form:

```vb
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim ses As New NotesSession
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set doc = ses.CurrentDatabase.CreateDocument
doc.Form = "FileSystemImage"
doc.ImageSource = "file:///C:/Images/Add.png"

ws.EditDocument , doc
```

Note that your image path must be formated in `url` format.

Comment: Wow. That worked flawlessly! I had to combine this with [this](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/dd507a5be7cc2e4285256eec005f56ef?OpenDocument) so I could refresh it at will. You saved me from writing a Java GUI. Thanks a lot!